# Sketch the unit ball $B(0, 1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with the norm $||(x,y)||=\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2}$

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Sketch the unit ball $B(0, 1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that has the norm:

$||(x,y)||=\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2}$

Im ok at sketching unit balls normally but the norm given has stumped me in making progress with this question so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The boundary of the ball is the curve $2 x^2 + 3 y^2 = 1$.  This is an ellipse...

Comment: If $\Vert\cdot\Vert_e$ is the euclidean norm, then the map $\phi:(\mathbb{R}^2,\Vert\cdot\Vert_e)\to(\mathbb{R}^2,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$, $\phi(x,y)=(x/\sqrt{2},y/\sqrt{3})$, is a linear isometry, so it maps unit balls to unit balls.

Answer (score 1):

The boundary of that unit ball would be the points $x,y$ so that $$\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2}=1 \iff 2x^2+3y^2=1$$

As they've already pointed out in the comments, that's the equation of an ellipse. It's easier to sketch it if you give some easy values to $x$ and $y$. For example, $x=0 \Rightarrow y=\frac{\pm1}{\sqrt3}$, $y=0 \Rightarrow x=\frac{\pm1}{\sqrt2}$...

Answer (score 1):

It's an ellipse passing through $||v_i||$ for $v_i\in\big\{(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)\big\}$.

[image]

*Note:* For generating such pictures by yourself you can use [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/) and enter `1 = sqrt(2x^2 + 3y^2)` in the bar at the bottom of the window.

Comment: [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%3Dsqrt(2x%5E2%2B3y%5E2)) is also good for these kind of tasks.